# ternary relationship from binary entity relationships

Tags: python, networkx, clique

I'm trying to capture intra sentence ternary relationships and eventually inter sentence .

Ex: Net revenues were $2.0 million and $3.0 million for year ending 2015,2016 respectively.

expected output : `(net revenues,$2.0 million,2015),(net revenues,$3.0 million,2016)`

Approaching this as a two step process

1. extracting binary relationships using bi-lstm attention network , the output of this is:

`(net revenues,$2.0 million),(net revenues,$3.0 million),(net revenues,2016),(net revenues,2015)`

2. Im trying to build a relationship graph with the position number of the entities and an edge between these entities if a label exists. Will generate cliques from this graph to create ternary relationships.

```
lines=["8 10 ","8 18","8 22 ","8 28","8 31","12 37"]
g1=nx.parse_edgelist(lines,nodetype=int)
for ab in nx.clique.find_cliques(g1):
    print(ab)
```

Without building the relationship graph I wanted to pass the edges as a list and see if it finds any cliques but the output is same as the input. Need some advice on this approach or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`nx.find_cliques` finds *all* cliques in a graph, even with `size == 2`. It means that this function returns all edges in addition to graph cliques. Your graph looks like this:

[image]

It has no `size >= 3` cliques so `nx.find_cliques` returns you just all edges in the graph. If we will add this edge:

`"10 31"`

```
import networkx as nx

lines = [ 
    "8 10",
    "8 18",
    "8 22",
    "8 28",
    "8 31",
    "12 37",
    "10 31"
]
g1 = nx.parse_edgelist(lines, nodetype=int)
for ab in nx.clique.find_cliques(g1):
    print(ab)
```

We will have one true clique:

```
[8, 10, 31]
[8, 18]
[8, 28]
[8, 22]
[12, 37]
```

And we can filter out all cliques with `size == 2`:

```
for ab in nx.clique.find_cliques(g1):
    if len(ab) > 2:
        print(ab)
```

So we will have only one `size >= 3` clique:

`[8, 10, 31]`

Comment: Thank you ,  I dont have enough reputation to upvote this answer . i have further question though if you don't mind.WIth 10 as common vertex and it was able create clique with size=3. How do I formulate it to use 8 as the common element.  By that I mean  say I get these as output of binary relationship

{ (8, 10): 'Element_date', (8, 18): 'Element_value', (8, 22): 'Element_date2', (8, 28): 'Element_value2', (8, 31): 'Element_date3', (8, 37): 'Element_value3'},

and the output is {(8,10,18),(8,22,28),(8,31,37)}

Comment: Looks like all Element_value nodes are not really nodes, but just attributes. You should group your dataset by Element_XXX pairs and set node attributes (see Attributes section here): https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html